# I need software that can extract some value in 1 big text file?

Tags: software-testing, text-search

I have really big text file, it is really a lot of text. I try to read it, but it is too much text.

I want to find some word, number, value in that file. I search but can't find the software that I need. i don't have time to read and find what I want in that file. How about, have a software, input a big text file, then select or extract specific value from this file. Please help. Thank-you.

Comment: Please define a) how big the text file is. There are several solutions for 10 MB files, but maybe just a few for 10 GB files. b) which operating system do you use c) what your budget is d) what does "exact same value" mean? Identical to what? What is the source for that value? Also a text file? Or user input?

Comment: Could you please use grammatical English. Capital letters to start sentences. This isn't a text message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on OS-X or Linux you have a number of possibilities such as `grep` or `sed` that will let you specify, on the command line, what to search for and the what to display around it.

On Windows 10 you can get the same functionality within the bash shell that you can optionally install or on all versions you can install [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) all of which include [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). With grep you can use:

```
grep -A 3 -B 2 "pattern" wildcard
```

Which will find *pattern* and display the 2 lines **B**efore and 3 lines **A**fter line it is on as well as the line itself in files that match the *wildcard*.

If you have python installed, *on OS-X or Linux you almost certainly will but on Windows you would need to [install python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/),* you can then add the [grin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin/) library and command line tool with `pip install grin` *(you may need to prefix with `sudo` on some systems)* to get similar functionality.

I tested grin with a big text file, (8.5 Gigabytes), and while it took a minute or four it successfully found the 2 lines that matched my target, *on lines 1048577 & 9437186*.